# Convert html or pdf document in postscript over web (PHP, JS)

Tags: php

I need print a document directly over PHP. It works by php_printer. Now I need convert HTML ou PDF document to PostScript.

It's possible over web? By Js ou PHP?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With PHP you can use [wkhtmltopdf](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/), you will have to install it on server though. It's a command line tool, but there are some PHP libraries, like [phpwkhtmltopdf](https://github.com/mikehaertl/phpwkhtmltopdf) to simplify the usage.

Comment: Thanks! But it isn't the problem, I asked wrong. Sorry! I edited the question. I need convert a PDF document to PostScript. It's possible?